# How can I convert multiple INSERT SQL statements into one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have an SQL file with 100 INSERT statements (see example below) which I have used to create an SQLITE database. I am now creating a MySQL database and want to convert this code into a single INSERT statement (example below.)

My main reason for doing this is just to make it look a little nicer. I was hoping that there would be a nice liitle online converter but i have been unable to find one so im here for suggestions.

Current SQL file is thousands of these:

```
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('955773', 'Mrs', 'Valle', 'Keave', '95380', 'Gale', 'Helena', 'Montana', '59623', '406-989-2003', 'vkeave0@shareasale.com', 'grow world-class deliverables');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('818817', 'Mrs', 'Melessa', 'Parmby', '914', 'Fairview', 'Montgomery', 'Alabama', '36114', '334-255-3054', 'mparmby1@addtoany.com', 'iterate seamless schemas');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('896697', 'Mrs', 'Cecil', 'Capsey', '05', 'Bay', 'Mesa', 'Arizona', '85215', '602-646-6128', 'ccapsey2@cnet.com', 'implement revolutionary functionalities');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('871100', 'Rev', 'Morgun', 'Coppeard', '049', 'High Crossing', 'Spokane', 'Washington', '99220', '509-838-3291', 'mcoppeard3@facebook.com', 'empower 24/365 users');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('589912', 'Mr', 'Ginger', 'Annandale', '7', 'Clove', 'Dayton', 'Ohio', '45403', '937-265-6244', 'gannandale4@nasa.gov', 'integrate clicks-and-mortar content');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('074451', 'Honorable', 'Nomi', 'Messitt', '402', 'Pond', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', '84115', '801-761-3351', 'nmessitt5@statcounter.com', 'empower dot-com channels');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('321380', 'Mr', 'Cris', 'De Giovanni', '7', 'Northland', 'Kansas City', 'Missouri', '64199', '816-646-5785', 'cdegiovanni6@uol.com.br', 'envisioneer intuitive paradigms');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('006367', 'Ms', 'Sherye', 'Commin', '72099', 'Crescent Oaks', 'Toledo', 'Ohio', '43666', '419-663-9711', 'scommin7@livejournal.com', 'visualize collaborative e-tailers');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('587714', 'Mr', 'Phedra', 'Scone', '478', 'Monterey', 'San Francisco', 'California', '94105', '310-116-1148', 'pscone8@myspace.com', 'matrix seamless bandwidth');
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes) values ('801027', 'Mrs', 'Bayard', 'Brindley', '76049', 'Duke', 'El Paso', 'Texas', '79968', '915-207-0519', 'bbrindley9@mysql.com', 'visualize enterprise networks');
```

What I want to achieve:

```
INSERT INTO
  customer (
    customer_id,
    customer_title,
    customer_forename,
    customer_surname,
    customer_address_1,
    customer_address_2,
    customer_town_city,
    customer_county,
    customer_postcode,
    customer_telephone_number,
    customer_email_address,
    customer_notes
  )
VALUES
  (
    1001,
    1002,
    1003,
    1004,
    1005,
    1006,
    1007,
    1008,
    1009,
    1010
  ),
  (
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR',
    'MR'
  ),
  (
    'Thomas',
    'Ben',
    'Rob',
    'Morgan',
    'Joe',
    'Samee',
    'Kitty',
    'Cameron',
    'Frank',
    'Eric'
  ),
  (
    'Masters',
    'Willy',
    'Norris',
    'Porch',
    'Mkoji',
    'Chouds',
    'Lewis',
    'Brooks',
    'Brown',
    'Cartman'
  ),
  (
    '6 Garthland Rd',
    '38 Downham Chase',
    '32 Bramside',
    '10 Rich Hill',
    '8 StockyP',
    '11 Hyde Rd',
    '18 BuzzinLa',
    '1 The Hills',
    '55 Pengting Rd',
    '10 Southpark'
  ),
  (
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies',
    'All Lies'
  ),
  (
    'Hazel Grove',
    'Timperley',
    'Bramhall',
    'Cheadle Hulme',
    'Stockport',
    'Hyde',
    'Liverpool',
    'New Mills',
    'Bolton',
    'Colorado'
  ),
  (
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County',
    'Some County'
  ),
  (
    'SK7 4NA',
    'SK12 1EF',
    'M4 1HJ',
    'NK7 6HG',
    'PK9 8II',
    'SW1A 1AA',
    'HG8 8IK',
    'HJ87 JKK',
    'SK12 1QJ',
    'N8 7HJ'
  ),
  (
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408',
    '07704768408'
  ),
  (
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM',
    'LIE@MADEUP.COM'
  ),
  (
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.',
    'Here are some notes.'
  );
```

If there is a quick fix for this that you know of then please let me know. The question that has been flagged as a duplicate of this is in now way the same. That question is about speed of query, this is about converting one format to another.

Comment: What do you mean? You can do that with an advanced text editor like Sublime Text and multicursors in like 30 seconds.

Comment: that might help if the topicstarter would have 100K+ or a even higher number inserts @lurker creating/opening a file, writing to a file, and opening it again to import with `LOAD DATA` also isn't "free" performance wise.. that method might be slower then the multi insert syntax for a low number number of records

Comment: @RaymondNijland the OP says they have 100 records, not 100k+.

Comment: "the OP says they have 100 records, not 100k+" @lurker  i mentioned the LOAD DATA is ideally for 100K+ or higher number of inserts, so the multi insert is most likely better in this case.. Making a CVS file plus using use LOAD DATA is just extra overhead for a low number of inserts..

Comment: @RaymondNijland roger that. I was just offering as an option. It's unclear whether it might be more convenient depending upon their broader use case.

Comment: @lurker this question is in no way a duplicate of the question that you have flagged up so please remove the marker and read both questions before flagging up.

Comment: @techouse that is exactly what I mean. If i download sublime text, will it convert the code from one format (multiple inserts) to the other ( a single insert with multiple values)?

Comment: @thomasters well it won't do it by itself, it's just a text editor. You will have to do it :) And for 100 lines that is most certainly a piece of cake.

Comment: This is a weird request. You'd normally want what GL suggests below.

Comment: If *This is what I want to achieve* is the exact form you want the data in, then it won't work since MySQL doesn't accept the data in that form.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert multiple records by doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes)
VALUES ('955773', 'Mrs', 'Valle', 'Keave', '95380', 'Gale', 'Helena', 'Montana', '59623', '406-989-2003', 'vkeave0@shareasale.com', 'grow world-class deliverables'),
('818817', 'Mrs', 'Melessa', 'Parmby', '914', 'Fairview', 'Montgomery', 'Alabama', '36114', '334-255-3054', 'mparmby1@addtoany.com', 'iterate seamless schemas'),
.
.
.
.
.
('801027', 'Mrs', 'Bayard', 'Brindley', '76049', 'Duke', 'El Paso', 'Texas', '79968', '915-207-0519', 'bbrindley9@mysql.com', 'visualize enterprise networks');
```

You have to break each new entry with a comma: `VALUES(.....), (........),` the last entry will then end with a semi-colon: `(......);`

Answer (score 0):

`insert` supports multiple values for `values`.  Doesn't this work for you?

```
insert into customer (customer_id, customer_title, customer_forename, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_telephone_number, customer_email_address, customer_notes)
    values ('955773', 'Mrs', 'Valle', 'Keave', '95380', 'Gale', 'Helena', 'Montana', '59623', '406-989-2003', 'vkeave0@shareasale.com', 'grow world-class deliverables'),
           ('818817', 'Mrs', 'Melessa', 'Parmby', '914', 'Fairview', 'Montgomery', 'Alabama', '36114', '334-255-3054', 'mparmby1@addtoany.com', 'iterate seamless schemas')
           . . .
```

So, you can insert multiple *rows* in a single `insert`.  However, you can't insert the data column by column.

Comment: doesnt `');` after the first query break the insert?

Comment: Yes I know, my question is that I have all of the data in the format of multiple inserts (as shown above) and would like to convert it into a single insert with multiple values like your example. I just don't want to do this manually.

Comment: @thomasters With a decent editor, manual conversion would take seconds. So why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert but in last secion of value you have to put semicollon and before last value section on each section you have to put comma EX:

```
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Page]
       ([PageTitle]
       ,[Link]
       ,[Status]
       ,[CreatedDate]
       ,[Description])
 VALUES
       ('demo','demo',1,'12/11/2019','demo'),
       ('demo','demo',1,'12/11/2019','demo'),
       ('demo','demo',1,'12/11/2019','demo'),
       ('demo','demo',1,'12/11/2019','demo'),
       ('demo','demo',1,'12/11/2019','demo');
```

Tested

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using phpMyAdmin (https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), just select the export table then export.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLrO5.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJ8R.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on below solution using a **PHP**,you can have a list of insert in form of array then you can specify counts per each insert group
I have used 2 functions

- ***get_string_between*** function
- ***joinInsertQueriesFromArray*** function

  ```
   function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
           $string = ' ' . $string;
           $ini = strpos($string, $start);
           if ($ini == 0) return '';
           $ini += strlen($start);
           $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
           return substr($string, $ini, $len);
   }

   /*
       VALUES ( -- cols -- );
       note: mantain space eg <-space-> VALUES <-space->(
   */
   function joinInsertQueriesFromArray($insertArray,$counts_per_group = 200){
       //$insertArray

       if(sizeof($insertArray) == 0) return [];

       //create a header from first query
       $query = $insertArray[0];
       $query = str_replace("values(", "VALUES (", $query);
       $query = str_replace("values (", "VALUES (", $query);
       $separator = strtoupper(" values (");
       $splitedQuery = explode($separator, $query);
       if(sizeof($splitedQuery) == 0) return [];
       $SQL_HEADER = $splitedQuery[0];
       //echo "HEADER - ".$SQL_HEADER."\n\n";

       //
       $insertSQLValuesArray = [];
       $groupSize = $counts_per_group;
       $currentInsertSQLValues = "";
       $createdAwbsListArray = [];

       for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($insertArray);$i++){
           $v = $insertArray[$i];
           $v = str_replace("values(", "VALUES (", $v);
           $v = str_replace("values (", "VALUES (", $v);

           $value = get_string_between($v,"VALUES (",");");

           $currentInsertSQLValues .= "(".$value.")";

           if(($i+1) % $groupSize == 0){
               array_push($insertSQLValuesArray, $currentInsertSQLValues.";");
               $currentInsertSQLValues = "";
           }else{
               $currentInsertSQLValues .= ",";
           }

       }
       if($currentInsertSQLValues != "") array_push($insertSQLValuesArray, rtrim($currentInsertSQLValues,",") .";");//values < group size:last values

       $statements = [];
       //combile INSERT INTO with values header + values
       for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($insertSQLValuesArray);$i++){
           $statement = $SQL_HEADER.' VALUES '.$insertSQLValuesArray[$i];
           array_push($statements, $statement);
       }

       //echo json_encode($statements);
       return $statements;

   }
  ```

**USAGE**

```
$list = [
            "INSERT into users(username,id) values ('GRAND',1);",
            "INSERT into users(username,id) values ('MASTER',2);",
            "INSERT into users(username,id) values ('DEOGRATIAS',3);",
            "INSERT into users(username,id) values ('DAMAS',4);",
            "INSERT into users(username,id) values ('NGEREZA',5);"
        ];
            $list = joinInsertQueriesFromArray($list,3);
            //echo json_encode($list);
```